# SSRS: Get backgroundcolor from Cell

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, background-color

I've got a report as a table. I would like to set for each column a random backgroundcolor.

For this i created a Custom Script:

```
Public Function GetColor()

    Dim intHighNumber AS Decimal = 255
    Dim intLowNumber AS Decimal = 100

    Dim NewColor AS String
    Dim Red AS Decimal = Int((intHighNumber - intLowNumber + 1) * Rnd + intLowNumber)
    Dim Green AS Decimal = Int((intHighNumber - intLowNumber + 1) * Rnd + intLowNumber)
    Dim Blue AS Decimal = Int((intHighNumber - intLowNumber + 1) * Rnd + intLowNumber)


    NewColor = "#" & Hex(Red) & Hex(Green) & Hex(Blue)

    Return NewColor
End Function
```

In the first cell i set the Fill Expression to: =code.GetColor()
Until here it works perfect, but now i want the same color for the rest of the Column... so I puted in the Expression "=Fields!myField.BackgroundColor" but this won't work...

I don't know how to fix this...

Thanks a lot for your help :-)

Comment: This is un-tested...but since the report engine generally writes left to right top to bottom you may be able to store a LastColorUsed public variable above your custom code functions. In your custom code create a function called LastColorUsed() that returns the last color used variable. That way you could either write the expression to be random or the last color used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to remember the colour setting for the column so you can reuse it in headers, footers, etc. We can achieve this with an array which returns a new colour first time called and the same colour for that index if that colour was previously assigned.

Here is the custom code:

```
Dim Colors(0 to 9) As String

Function GetColor(Color As Integer) As String
  Dim intHighNumber AS Decimal = 255 
  Dim intLowNumber AS Decimal = 100 
  Dim ThisColor AS String 

  if (Colors(Color) <> "") Then
    ThisColor = Colors(Color) 
  else 
    Dim Red AS Decimal = Int((intHighNumber - intLowNumber + 1) * Rnd + intLowNumber) 
    Dim Green AS Decimal = Int((intHighNumber - intLowNumber + 1) * Rnd + intLowNumber) 
    Dim Blue AS Decimal = Int((intHighNumber - intLowNumber + 1) * Rnd + intLowNumber) 
    ThisColor = "#" & Hex(Red) & Hex(Green) & Hex(Blue) 
    Colors(Color) = ThisColor
  End If 

  Return ThisColor 
End Function
```

Then in your cells, you simply call the `GetColor` function passing the colour index number that you want the cell to have. For instance, the first column's header, detail, and footer cells' `BackgroundColor` property expression would all be:

```
=Code.GetColor(0)
```

Then you just use a different colour index for each column.

Make sure you dimension the array with enough room to store all your colours (or you could also `ReDim` your array each time you add a new colour if you want to use a dynamic array instead).

Answer (score 0):

```
Private string _LastColorUser="" 

Public Function LastColorUsed()
  Return _LastColorUsed
End Function

Public Function GetColor()

    Dim intHighNumber AS Decimal = 255
    Dim intLowNumber AS Decimal = 100

    Dim NewColor AS String
    Dim Red AS Decimal = Int((intHighNumber - intLowNumber + 1) * Rnd + intLowNumber)
    Dim Green AS Decimal = Int((intHighNumber - intLowNumber + 1) * Rnd + intLowNumber)
    Dim Blue AS Decimal = Int((intHighNumber - intLowNumber + 1) * Rnd + intLowNumber)


    NewColor = "#" & Hex(Red) & Hex(Green) & Hex(Blue)

    _LastColorUser=NewColor;  

    Return NewColor
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this don't work, I get different colors for a few Cells. Not the same for the whole Column.

Answer (score 0):

@Chris Thank you this is what i needed.
Because my Columns were dynamic I had to write another function to get a Number:

```
Public Function GetColumnNumber(ByVal parameter as Parameter,ByVal SSID As String) as String
      For i as integer = 0 to parameter.Count-1
         If CStr(parameter.Value(i)) = SSID THEN
          Return i
         END IF
      Next
End Function
```

In the Cell i wrote this:

```
=code.GetColor(code.GetColumnNumber(Parameters!SSID,Fields!SSID.Value))
```

Thanks again :)