# SQL Reporting - Get previous row properties

Tags: formatting, ssrs-2008-r2

I would like to get the background color specified in the previous row.
So instead of Previous(Fields!xxx.Value) something like Previous(Fields!xxx.Color).

I can't find any documentation of which options i can use instead of .Value.
Any suggestions?

What i want to achieve is change the background color of my row if a member changes, but the color i want to change it to should be dependant of the color of the previous row.

Thanks in advance.

Marc

Comment: Probably you want alternate color depending on group or the row.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way I know to check the previous cells color unless you set it with custom code. Check out: [SSRS: Get backgroundcolor from Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19639083/ssrs-get-backgroundcolor-from-cell)

If you were only alternating colors you could do the following:

`=IIF(Previous(Fields!FieldName.Value) = Fields!FieldName.Value, "Blue", "Red")`

Depending on how many members you had and what colors you wanted you could always specify the colors based on the member with a default color.

`=IIF(Fields!FieldName.Value = "SomeMember1", "Blue", "Red")
=IIF(Fields!FieldName.Value = "SomeMember2", "Blue", "Red")
=IIF(Fields!FieldName.Value = "SomeMember3", "Blue", "Red")`