# Changing Textbox value color based on Background color

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I want to change the Textbox value color based on the background color. How can i do it?

Unfortunately I can't use expression in my case for Textbox value color, since Background color has following calculation `iif(exp1,red, iif(exp2,yellow,white))` to show Red and Yellow color and the textbox has a single `iif` likewise `iif(exp1 or exp2,blue,black)`, apart of the formula it satisfies both `exp1` and `exp2` and change Textbox value color to blue in both red and yellow background even though it applies to only one background color.

What I am trying to explain is I can't use expression in my case for Textbox value color, I need to depend background color, is it possible?

Comment: Why can't you set the Color using your expression `iif(exp1 or exp2,blue,black)`?

Comment: If all of your expression fields are full, custom code will be the way to go.
See; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19639083/ssrs-get-backgroundcolor-from-cell and http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Reporting+Services+(SSRS)/116006/